# sum of the amounts in a file should be stored as single value in an shell variable

Tags: shell-script

```
H|~^20200425|~^abcd|~^sum
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-06T12:33:52.27|~^1000123.34567|~^2018-04-12T12:33:52.27|
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-05T12:33:52.27|~^111930.02876|~^2018-10-23T12:33:52.27|
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-05T12:33:52.27|~^2112320.028|~^2018-10-24T12:33:52.27|
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-06T12:33:52.27|~^12230.0809|~^2018-09-11T12:33:52.27|
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-05T12:33:52.27|~^3076543789.00878|~^2018-08-05T12:33:52.27|
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-06T12:33:52.27|~^156655.0389|~^2018-10-23T12:33:52.27|
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-06T12:33:52.27|~^10453.0489|~^2018-04-08T12:33:52.27|
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-05T12:33:52.27|~^20654.0907|~^2018-07-23T12:33:52.27|
```

I need to get the sum of the total amounts in the 4th field for the record starts from 'R'. I wanted sum of amounts of all the rows to be stored in a variable. how to achieve it

Comment: what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
variable=$( awk -F '^' '$1 == "R|~" { sum += $4 } END { print sum }' file )
```

The `awk` command treats the data as `^`-delimited and sums the 4th field up from each line that has an `R` in the first field, and then prints the sum when all data has been read.  The non-numerical data at the end of the field (the string `|~`) will be ignored during the conversion of the field's data to a numerical value.

The output of the `awk` command is then assigned to a variable using a standard command substitution.

---

For really big numbers, use `bc`:

```
variable=$(
    awk -F '^' '$1 == "R|~" { sub("\\|.*","",$4); print $4 "+\\" } END { print "0" }' file  |
    bc
)
```

This prints out the sum as a computation for `bc` to handle.  The `bc` utility is [a standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/bc.html) arbitrary precision calculator.

Comment: You could use `-F '\\|~\\^'` to split it at the "exact" pattern ...

Comment: Thanks mate @kusalananda!. I tried this but amount value can be 31 digits before"."and 5 digits decimal precession. its not working as expected when i aplly the above solution. Can you help me out how to achieve this?

Comment: @hunter I can only see the data that you include in the question. Please update your question with representative data.

Comment: @kusalananda I have updated the question. To summarise the amount value can be upto 31 digits before"." And upto 5 decimal precessions. When i add the value i should get all the precisons

Comment: @hunter See updated answer

Comment: @Kusalananda, Thanks a lot It's working. Thanks for investing some time and giving me a prompt solution.

Comment: @Kusalananda, I have got stuck on the similar lines with the edited question. Could you please take a look and suggest me something to get on the shore. Thanks in Advance. Sorry to Trouble you.

Comment: @hunter The edit constitutes a separate question. It's more than a small addition to the current question. You should ask it separately.

Comment: @Kusalananda, I will post a separate one. Can you please help.

Comment: @hunter I look at questions that I find interesting, that's all I can promise. It's also well after midnight where I am. We'll see tomorrow.

Comment: @Kusalananda, Oh sorry, I have posted a new question by d way!. if possible kindly help. I'm kind of stuck from 2 days. sorry once again for the trouble